# Mounting & Unmounting Network Shares on a mobile laptop

Tags: laptop, fstab, gvfs

I have no problem mounting my shares (fstab or Gigolo). What I looking for is a way to automatically unmount the shares when I disconnect from the network and reconnect when I return.
Gigolo seems close. It reconnects fine, but I still seem to have to manually disconnect from each share individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for in the Ubuntu Forums.

[HOWTO: Automatically mount and unmount shares (alternative version)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=637258)

It automatically mounts and unmounts shares as they come and go.
I've used this method on Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04, and Debian Squeeze and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a script. This is a skeleton / template, call it net_mount and put it in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`

```
#!/bin/sh
# auto mount/umount network shares

IF=$1
STATUS=$2

# set your desired network here
NETMASK="192.168.0.0/24"

mount_shares (){
    # command(s) to mount shares here
    mount share1
    mount share2
    ....
}

umount_shares (){
    # command(s) to un-mount shares here
    umount share1
    umount share2
    ....
}

if [ -n "`/sbin/ip addr show $IF to $NETMASK`" ]; then
case "$STATUS" in
    up)
        mount_shares
        ;;
    pre-down)
        umount_shares
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
else
    umount_shares
fi
```

Make it executable

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/net_mount
```

Comment: Thanks. So this script will be used in conjunction with fstab or should everything be done in the script? 
ie /etc/fstab :  //192.168.0.100/example           /mnt/example     cifs   username=user,password=1234

Comment: You have to fill in how to mount your shares. If they are in fstab, `mount /mnt/example`. Personally I would add them to fstab with the noauto option.

Comment: I seem to still have an issue. It mounts fine,  but as an example if I pull the network cable nothing gets unmounted. My conky script hangs and if I try to go to /mnt it sits there spinning. As soon as I put the cable back in /mnt loads and conky starts working again. Am I missing something in my fstab?

//192.168.0.150/videos          /mnt/videos      cifs   noauto,username=user,dir_mask=0777,password=1234,rw 0 0

Comment: The script is for connecting and disconnecting with network manager. Why are you pulling your network cable ? Disconnect and re-connect with NM, pull the cable after you disconnect and before you re-connect.

Comment: Makes no difference. I tried "Disconnect" from the network manager and got the exact same result. Everything hangs

Comment: does it hang if your shares are not mounted and you then disconnect ?

Comment: No it doesn't hang when the drives aren't mounted. Also, this morning I moved from home (192.168.0.0) to work (192.168.1.0) and the drives are still mounted. So nothing is unmounting still